# KTM electrical system fried

Tags: electrical, ktm

So a week ago I put in a LED bulb in my KTM 450 headlight. It turned on working fine, then everything just shut off. I took it to a dealership and they told me that you need a LED conversion kit for it; that’s fair enough. But then they told me I put positive on negative and negative on positive. He said it fried the whole electrical system including the harness stator.... etc. He also said it was grounded. I’m really confused because I don’t think it could have caused that much damage. There should surely be a fuse or a safety. Are they trying to scam me?

Comment: Also I forgot to say I have warranty with the bike

Comment: First, things first. Diodes(like Light Emiting Diodes - LED) likes their current flowing only in one direction, doing the other way around would certianlly fry them, in your case the led light. Second, look in you manual for all of the fuses and start pulling them out, sometimes there is a big one near the battery(my street triple has a 30amp fuse under the seat and all of the other fuses are located under the tank). Third, get a hold of voltmeter and check your stator for continuity(look for this topic in triumphrat forum) before the R/R, they shouldn't read open(1 ohm).

Answer (score 1):

The warranty may not cover damage caused by you in this situation. Making unauthorized changes is not always covered and you may well find you will have to pay for the repairs.